# Why is OnClickListener never called while OnLongClickListener is

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have an Adapter for a RecyclerView. It registers click listeners for the views:

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductCardViewHolder {
        val productView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_card_item, parent, false)
        val holder = ProductCardViewHolder(productView)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(it.context, "CLICK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(it.context, "LONG", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            false
        }

        return holder
}
```

And that is the layout (`R.layout.product_card_item`)

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/product_img"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

When I long press the item it invokes the long click listener fine, but when I just click the item, the click listener is never invoked, Why is that?

Comment: can you show `onBindViewHolder` method? it should work, but maybe in some other place you are overriding this listener (or framework do this under the hood)

Comment: @snachmsm I found the issue I think, it seems like a Android Studio problem, when I hit "apply changes and run" the listener does not get invoked, like the changes werent applied. But after deleting the app on the device and reinstalling it works perfectly